# Traffic coming from campaign shows as direct traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

When User coming from the Google advards or facebook ads. It count in a direct traffic instead of refferal traffic.
I use redirection on landing page of website.So, when user type www.xyz.com it will redirect to the home page.
My question is that how can i identify that how much traffic is coming from refferal and direct.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to tag the URLs with the UTM parameters in order to breakdown the data of the campaigns.

With adwords you can use the auto-tagging, which allows you to do it automatically: 
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1752125?hl=en

As for other platforms such as Facebook, you will need to tag them manually. 
It will look like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_campaign=facebook-summer-promotion&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=blue-teaser
```

Read more about it here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en&ref_topic=1032998

Note that if you use redirections from the landing page, you must make sure that the parameters are passed with it, so you won't lose the campaign information.

After you've done so, you will see this data in Traffic sources-->Campaigns.

Comment: @dm..Thanks for this answer. It helps me alot and now problem is resolved.